# SignalR connection with typescript in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I already have SignalR installed in my project. I implemented an example with jQuery. I want to do the same example with TypeScript.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu4ce.png)

Vıew:

```
const a = "Hollo Word";
document.getElementById('textDiv').textContent = a;

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/CovidHub").build();
connection.start().then(() => {
    debugger;

}).catch((err) => {
    alert('Error:' + err);
});



@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="~/js/TsConvertToJs/app.js"></script>
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="textDiv"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have TypeScript code like below. But I can't connect to signalR.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/CovidHub").build();
connection.start().then(() => {
    debugger;

}).catch((err) => {
    alert('Error:' + err);
});
```

> Error:`TS2304: (TS) Connot find name 'signalR'`

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/TsConvertToJs",
    "rootDir": "TypeScript"
  },
  "include": [
    "TypeScript/**/*"
  ]
}
```

libman.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "unpkg",`
  "libraries": [`
    {
      "library": "@microsoft/signalr@6.0.6",
      "destination": "wwwroot/microsoft/signalr/",
      "files": [
        "dist/browser/signalr.js",
        "dist/browser/signalr.min.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.0-dev.20230131"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already have SignalR installed in my project. I implemented an
> example with jQuery. I want to do the same example with TypeScrip. I
> have TypeScript code like below. But I can't connect to signalR.

Well, based on your description it seems that your client is not getting the proper referece of your hub and throwing that error. As per my investigation, I think your following script causing the issue as it doesn't seems correct.

```
    <script src="~/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="~/js/TsConvertToJs/app.js"></script>
```

If you follow [correct steps as per official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-signalr-client-library), your script should be as following:

```
   <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
   <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

Please, make sure you have gone through the following steps:

[image]

**About Typescript and javascript Implememtation:**

As you may know SignalR both has [Typescript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) implementations which are quite different than each other. In this reagards, make sure, you have followed exact architecture and steps.

TypeScript Architecture:

[image]

Note: Please [check our official document for details steps with working sample.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-the-client)

**Output:**

[image]

Javascript Architecture:

[image]

Chat.js Implementation:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Note: Please [check our official document for details steps for Javascript with working sample.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-signalr-client-code)

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** I would suggest you to follow either of the implementation guideline first. Once you would be familier with the configuration and steps, you would be more competent for any customization. Therefore, [this official document help you to implement correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-signalr-client-code).